# Convert double to uint and retour

Tags: c++

I try to convert a value from modbus. 
The device show "-1.0", the retourned value is 65535 (uint16).
I try now to convert this value retour in double. 
I have tried it with different cast's.
It gives me always 65353.00  :(

How do we convert negative uint values in double?

```
typedef unsigned short uint16;

int main() {

double dRmSP = -1.0;                       //-1.0000   ok
uint16 tSP = static_cast<uint16>(dRmSP);   // = 65535   ok

// retour
double _dRmSP = static_cast<double>(tSP);  // = 65535.0000  why??

// try
double _dRmSP_ = static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>(tSP));    // =65535.0000  why??

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative unsigned values, by definition do not exist.   So you can't convert one to anything.

Your actual situation is that - in getting data from your device - the value of `-1.0` is converted to an `unsigned` value first.   The logic, since `-1.0` is outside the range of values that an `unsigned` can represent is to use modulo arithmetic.

The way this works, for a negative input value (like `-1.0`) and an `unsigned` variable with maximum value `65535` (corresponding to a 16-bit `unsigned`) is to keep adding `65536 = 65535 + 1` until a result is obtained between `0` and `65535`.    For `-1.0` this produces a result of `65535.0`.   When that value is converted to an `unsigned`, the result is therefore `65535`.

That explains why you are getting a value of `65535` when your device displays `-1.0`.

What you are trying to do with the "retour" is reverse the process.  It is not enough to convert an `unsigned` to a `double` (as you are) since a `double` can represent `65535.0` (at least, within limits of numerical precision).

The first step is to convert your value to a `double` (which will convert `65535` to `65535.0`, because a `double` can represent values like that (again within limits of floating point precision).

The next step - which you are not performing - requires you need to have some idea of what the minimum (or maximum) value is that your device actually supports - which you need to get from documentation.   For example, if the minimum value your device can represent is `-100.0`  (or the maximum is `65435.0`) then you reverse the process - keep subtracting `65536.0` until a result is obtained between `-100.0` and `65435.0`.

In code, this might be done by

```
double dRmSP = -1.0;                       //-1.0000   ok
uint16 tSP = static_cast<uint16>(dRmSP);   // = 65535   ok

// retour
double dRmSP = static_cast<double>(tSP);  // = 65535.0000  - as described above

while (dRmSP > 65435.0) dRmSP -= 65536.0;   //  voila!  -1.0 obtained
```

Comment: Best explained steps how to back retour from a "negative" uint value to double. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

You're taking the `uint16` value 65535 and turning it into a `double`. This is 65535.0.
There is no other valid expectation.

The variable `tSP` does not "remember" that its value originally came from a `double` of value `-1.0`. `tSP` is the unsigned integer value `65535`; period.

> How do we convert negative uint values in double?

There are no "negative uint values". The "u" stands for unsigned which means negative values are not in the domain of values of that type.

If you wish to use `dRmSP` then use `dRmSP`, not some other variable with a different type and value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are no negative unsigned int values. Unsigned means there is no sign bit.

What you did was:

```
uint16 t1(-1.0); // wraps around to positive 65535
auto t2 = static_cast<double>(t1); // turns 65535 to 65535.0 (no wrapping)
```

If you want this to work for negative values use an `int` or comparable (non unsigned integral) type. But if you do this then remember that you will lose a bit for the value (if you use int16).